# Where to put personalized recommendations feature?

Tags: usability

I would like to add a Personalized recommendations feature to my E-comm website. Should I add it as a floating,fixed button on the side? Is that considered something users are annoyed by? If I shouldn't, which method is recommended for Personalized recommendations

Comment: Hi Nirupama - can you add some more context to this? What does your current website look like? What is the design of the button you're thinking about implementing?

Answer (score 2):

Multiple factors come into picture especially for ecomm sites,

Consider following points when referring to what you call 'Personal Recommendation'

**How much agressive you want to be**

-> If you want to make your user's to first checkout products that you recommended based on their past purchase than put it at the top. But make sure that you have good algorithms that display relevant product for that

-> You can put it at the left or right side as 'Are you looking for',  'You might be interested in', "You might like this' But limit it to only 3-4 products display and add something like 'See more' at the bottom which will display more products.

-> You can put it at the bottom as 'Recommended for you' within the slider like < >

But at the end it's also depends on your website design.

Answer (score 2):

### It also depends on what you sell or advertise.

Some personal experience...

One web shop with a very large range of products (Amazon) prominently displayed, over the course of a few months, a very specific recommendation (gay porn). The first time this happened to me while I was researching technical literature, for my team members on the job, at my workplace. No idea on why Amazon thought I would be interested in gay porn (I am defiantly not), but the recommendation was there. Now, don't get me wrong: I am not homophobic, just plain hetero, but an advertising for porn is not the coolest thing to have on the screen at work. Regardless of the relevance or irrelevance of the pick.

It does not need to be gay porn. Are you a fan of Science Fiction writer Charles Stross? In that case, Amazon might recommend *Saturn's Children*, most probably the U.S. cover version. Some people might get the wrong idea when they see that cover suddenly popping up on your screen... Many U.S. customers specifically ordered the British edition, in order to be able to read the book in public without getting funny looks from bystanders. Unlike my "gay porn experience", this cover is rather tame, but still considered "too much" by some persons.

So, if your product range could cause embarrassment on the customer's side, don't pop up your recommendation at the top of the page right at the start. And give the user to quickly scroll away from anything possibly offending. Not like a full-screen popup which requires you to locate and hit a tiny close button to get rid of some "personal hygiene recommendation" or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

The priority of the merchandiser should always be to make the list of recommended items **available** to the user without interrupting the natural flow of the eye. The term **available** is emphasized because it should be there as a part of the composition of the page without unwanted artificiality, that the user shouldn't feel like it is being forced onto them.

A sudden popup with a so called "recommended item" on the face while browsing the catalog would do more harm than good when the overall experience is taken into account. The practical way to make this clear to you would be to think of the current patterns available to us. Since we are interested in E-comm websites here, lets take the prime example of e-commerce giant [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/).

[image]

Among the plethora of available items and daily deals (Image: consider the smartphones section and the laptop section), Amazon managed to show this particular user (a test subject for this scenario) deals on hard disk drives. Now for an external party looking onto the very same web page, nothing particular is worth mentioning. But for a returning user who has recently browsed the hard drive section of the site, a section featuring the items that he/she is interested in, subtly merged, but adequately distinctive, would definitely be interesting.

A dedicated side panel (with a floating button) could also work, but the cognitive approach suggests us not to impart the notion that an activity is forced onto to the user.

Your best bet would be to add the items within the browsing space, in a way that it goes with the regular flow of the display progression.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

#### Stick with Convention

Taking two top examples, see Amazon and Netflix below(Netflix isn't exactly Ecomm, but it's certainly a site optimized around personalized consumption) it's fair to say that **delivering personalized content as a main and prioritized component of the page**, is a technique worth considering.

#### Avoid Technical Issues

Designing a personalized recommendation section into the main structure of your page is going to be more robust in the long run, or at least, will be less likely to give issues e.g. on mobile devices than your floating button solution.

---

**Design your personalized recommendation section into the main structure of your page.**

---

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks Dennis. You have given clear description. But still my manager is asking me to put on top of the homepage as a hyperlink. Where user can see immediately. Once the user logs in and purchased some thing in the site. The next visit he will get the " Recommendation for you as a hyperlink at the top header of the home page. Link will be present in all the pages where it can grab user attention. Please suggest.

Comment: @NirupamaPrasanna Sounds like your manager is going to determine what happens here. As a manager he or she obviously know the right answer to every problem ; )  If you can't push back against your manager, then you don't really have an option but to do what s/he says.

Answer (score 1):

## Personalize at the beginning

Wherever your users start their journey is where you want to hit them with recommendations. That's usually the homepage, though there may be many depending on the way you route users. Catching the customer early in the visit can prevent them from running off on unproductive paths and ultimately bailing in frustration.

## Don’t over do it

Realistically, you don't usually want to go nuts with the recommendations. Unless you get Amazon's repeat order rate or you only have five products, there's a good chance you don't *really* know what your customer wants. With that in mind, you'll still have lots of real estate on the page devoted to other "standard" promotions.

## Expand on demand

But what if you're really on to something and the user just loves your reco's? Why not let them explore a bit more? Provide a link from the lander and something in the footer or top nav where the user can jump to an expanded list of recommendations.

## Local recommendations

Personalized recommendations depend on a lot of traffic from one user and a solid algorithm cross-referencing and forecasting against that data. But at the product or category level you're likely to have more data across your customer base. In addition to the personalized listings on the lander, you can promote recommendations on the product page or in the cart (depending on it's contents).

Answer (score 1):

Recommendation must always be provided keeping in mind that you might not be entirely correct in suggestions. Amazon does a very bad job as it keeps suggesting long list of products over he entire page.

[image: Amazon recommendation]

Now not only does an e commerce site needs to provide recommendations based on user's past search but also promote it's current deals.

Here's is what i suggest:

Collapsing different categories into one.

[image]

Above design allows me space to show more deals, more recommendation along with better clarity for user to choose option.

Answer (score 0):

I guess recommended feature should be placed at the bottom of the page but should be sticky in Cart Page why I mean to say that, customer shop the things and if he/she is interested in buying another item, will for sure scroll here and there so in that case, it will be benefited for website. and at last when they are done with payment and processing recommended for you option should be there because can force at that time as good marketing tricks